# package and distribute exe for Java application with DB and third party lib using netbeans

Tags: java, swing

**I have create an application (in java swing ) using netbeans, There are a database connectivity using derby and more external jar file included in project.**

I want to create setup of java app

I followed these steps:

1. Create jar for project (Clean and build project from tools)
2. Goto project and open dist folder, here is no DB folder so I copied DB folder (APPDATA) and paste it to dist folder.
3. Now I create .exe from third party tools
4. When my Database folder places in same directory then exe run perfectly.

But my question is **how I can package .jar with APPDATA(Database folder) which can run reliably and independently in other systems** as exe.

**So I can able to make installer in future** for same product.

**Only window exe creation and packaging solution is enough.**

Comment: where is this question `swing` or `java` relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tools like Install Shield or NSIS for installation to build your exe which can open a zip file , extract and execute batch \ shell scripts in which you can do whatever you want like installing your third party database & running your application jar.

I personally like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#fileformat)
as it is completely script based and open source .